# Why can't I install ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu via apt-get?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

```
apt-get install ruby
```

Installs ruby 1.8.7

When I install ruby 1.9.2 from sources via ./configure make install, ruby is not installed (ruby -v gives nothing).

So how can I install ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use rvm Ruby Version Manager on my  ubuntu-10.04.1-desktop.  With ruby-1.9.2 , ruby 1.8.7 
no problem.

Answer (score 1):

- on 10.10 "Maverick Meerkat": `apt-get install ruby1.9.1`
- on 10.04 "Lucid Lynx": Ruby 1.9.2 was only released a couple of weeks ago, it didn't exist when Lucid was frozen.

Comment: will apt-get install ruby1.9.1 install ruby 1.9.2? 1.9.1 doesn't work with Rails

Comment: @Alex: Yes, on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat (and current Debian, too), the version of the `ruby1.9.1` package is 1.9.2, which you can easily check by looking at `apt-cache show ruby1.9.1` or http://Packages.UbuntuLinux.Org/ruby1.9.1 or http://Packages.Debian.Org/ruby1.9.1

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to download new ubuntu and try that.

Comment: Sheesh, good to know that rvm is still the only sane option, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ruby 1.9.1 with

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1
```

ruby 1.9.2 is not available for lucid (but I have not checked backports).

Comment: I see package rails, that depends on ruby1.8. I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, 1.8 works, but 1.9.x is a lot faster. That's why I want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also proceed to upgrade the ruby installation,
as below,

sudo apt-get upgrade ruby